# Issues with deleting active projects on GCP "Folder cannot be deleted as it contains active resources."

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

Recently I have been having a lot of issues with google. I've come to decide to delete my workspace account, although that has not been straightforward. At the moment, when going to the deletion page, I'm prompted with an error

> "*You have active projects in Google Cloud Platform. You need to
> delete all GCP projects before you can delete this account. Learn
> more*"

I click on the link and gain access to GCP, a service that I've never been aware of or personally used. I simply try to select my resources to delete, and am prompted to re-confirm the folder ID, which I do. Upon progressing, I am prompted with this message

> "*Folder Service Folder cannot be deleted as it contains active
> resources. Only empty folders can be deleted.*"

I then delve down a long several-hour search on google communities and Stack overflow to find an answer, though nothing seems to help me progress. I managed to find someone who mentioned that I should try checking https://script.google.com/home  I did indeed check and there were a few google sheets documents that I had, so I deleted those and now my apps script page is empty.

I then re-tried to delete the resources back in GCP and I still am prompted with the folder service error as mentioned above.

I'm not hugely tech literate, though, with a bit of guidance, I should be able to carry out whatever needs to be done to help resolve this issue.

I'd be incredibly grateful for any help with the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it sounds like you still have GCP project(s) inside the folder that prevents deletion.

You can check the list of active projects from Cloud Resource Manager page (https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager) if there is any project inside the folder so that you can delete them accordingly. Then, delete the empty folder in the last step.

Comment: let me know in the comment if you have stuck with any of these steps.

Comment: I would consider just stop paying my bill and let them figure it out.

Comment: I never try to stop paying the bill before. I'm not sure if the system allows users to do that. It never hurt to try checking if anything is running right now. https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/

Comment: So this doesn't seem to work, If I go to that link, I get this: https://imgur.com/a/I8aTzBU
And upon trying to delete the child folder, I go back to step one with the "Folder Service Folder cannot be deleted as it contains active resources. Only empty folders can be deleted." message. Also Fony Lew, nothing shows up under billing.

Comment: I will also add I was trying to delete the files with the CLI/Terminal 
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.delete) User [info@myemailhere.co.uk] does not have permission to access projects instance [project number here] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission

But I have put my user as an admin, owner, file deleter and many other relevant options in the IAM permissions folder.

Comment: To additionally add, I figured I try logging into a different account and have progressed. I managed to figure out it was something tied with my sheets. I have been able to shut down all 10 of the projects. https://imgur.com/a/16ZdJWE

And with that, I was able to delete my apps script folder obviously, thought I'm still unable to delete it's parent folder "system-gsuite" with the same error "Folder Service Folder cannot be deleted as it contains active resources. Only empty folders can be deleted."

Answer (score 0):

Try to check for projects which are in an upcoming deletion cycle within your cloud CLI: `gcloud projects list --filter='lifecycleState:DELETE_REQUESTED'`

It can take up to one month until your projects are finally deleted.